# stl function in R is not recognising a univariate time series

Tags: r, stl

I am using R to read a time series from Excel (using XLConnect), then running some forecast models on that time series, and then outputting the results back to Excel.  It's a long story, but the company I'm doing a Masters by Research for want to keep using Excel!  Anyhow, I can extract the time series I want from Excel.  I use ts() to make it a time series.  I then run forecasts on that series using (in this order) `ets()`, `auto.arima()`, `tbats()`, `mapaest()`, `theta()`, and finally `stlf()`.  To check that it's doing the forecasts I get R to print off the results of the forecasts.  It runs through all the forecast models fine until it gets to the `stlf()` forecast function.  When I get this error:

> Error in stl(x, s.window = s.window, t.window = t.window, robust =
>   robust) :    only univariate series are allowed

My question is how come the time series (it is univariate) works fine in the other forecast functions but not in the `stlf()` function?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out now after doing some more digging around.  It turns out that I was passing a time series that was also a matrix to the `stlf()` function.  The other forecasting functions don't seem to mind being given a time series that is also a matrix, but for some reason `stlf()` doesn't like it.

I converted my raw data into a vector using `as.vector()` and then turned that vector into a `ts()` object.  And then passed that onto the `stlf()` function.  Not massivly sure how this works as I originally passed a `ts()` object to `stlf()` previously.  Fairly new to R, but I will look further into this..

Here is the code I used ;

```
altVector <- as.vector(t(rawdata))
      tsy2 <- ts(altVector, start=1, end=c(3,9), frequency=12)
      f.stlf <- stlf(tsy2, method="arima", h=3)
```

It's all working fine now.